# Problemas com aplicação de filtro gaussiano

Tags: c, processamento-de-imagens

A função deveria apenas aplicar o filtro gaussiano numa imagem PPM, porém o resultado são várias imagens filtradas sobrepostas. Alguma sugestão ?

[edit]  [imagem antes do filtro](http://www.dropbox.com/s/iwwm15bs6zbf7oa/imagem_cinza.ppm?dl=0) | [imagem após o filtro](http://www.dropbox.com/s/rkdg227akklmk4f/imagem_filtrada.ppm?dl=0) | [resultado esperado](http://www.dropbox.com/s/hh6ka1czc4b8o4r/imagem_desejada.jpg?dl=0)

```
pixel** gauss_filter(pixel** picture, int* L, int* C)
{    
    float novopixel = 0.;
    float peso = 0.;        
    int i, j = 0;        
    int a, b = 0;


    float filter[5][5] =    {{(2.),(4.),(5.),(4.),(2.)},
                            {(4.),(9.),(12.),(9.),(4.)},
                            {(5.),(12.),(15.),(12.),(5.)},
                            {(4.),(9.),(12.),(9.),(4.)},
                            {(2.),(4.),(5.),(4.),(2.)}};

    pixel** new_picture = (pixel**)malloc(*L * sizeof(pixel*)); 

    for(i = 0; i < *L; i++)
    {       
      new_picture[i] = (pixel*) malloc(*C * sizeof(pixel));

      for(j = 0; j < *C; j++)
      {   
        novopixel = 0.;
        peso = 0.;

        for(a = -2; a <= 2; a++)
        {               
            for(b = -2; b <= 2; b++)
            {
                if((i+a >= 0 && i+a < *L) && (j+b >= 0 && j+b < *C))
                { 
                    //Estou usando uma imagem em tons de cinza
                    //por isso calculo um canal e repito o valor
                    //nos outros canais

                    novopixel += (picture[i+a][j+b].r * filter[a+2][b+2]);
                    peso += filter[a+2][b+2];
                }                       
            }
        }

        novopixel = novopixel/peso;

        new_picture[i][j].r = (int)novopixel;
        new_picture[i][j].g = (int)novopixel;
        new_picture[i][j].b = (int)novopixel;
      }
    }

    free(picture);

    picture = new_picture;

    return picture;
}

//======================================================================

pixel** create_picture(FILE *arq, int* L, int* C)
{
    int i, j = 0;
    //armazena tipo do arquivo
    char tipo[3];
    //buffer para leitura do arquivo
    char line[64];
    //controla a leitura do cabecalho
    int flag = 0;
    int componente = 0;

    while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, arq) )
    {   //primeira linha: tipo
        if(flag == 0)
        {
            sscanf(line, "%s", tipo);
            printf("\ntipo: %s",tipo);
            flag += 1;
        }
        //terceira linha: dimensoes 
        if(flag == 2)
        {
            sscanf(line, "%d %d", &*L, &*C);
            printf("\nlinhas: %d colunas: %d", *L, *C);
            flag +=1;
        }
        //valor de componente
        if(flag == 3)
        {
            fgets(line, sizeof line, arq);
            sscanf(line, "%d", &componente);
            printf("\ncomponente: %d", componente);
            if(componente != 255)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nComponente de imagem RGB invalido (%d)\n", componente);
                exit(1);
            }
            break;
        }
        //segunda linha: comentarios
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            fgets(line, sizeof line, arq);
            flag += 1;
        }
    }

    if (tipo[0] != 'P' || tipo[1] != '3')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Formato de arquivo invalido ('%c%c')\n", tipo[0], tipo[1]);
        exit(1);
    } 

    pixel** picture = (pixel**)malloc(*L * sizeof(pixel*));

    for (i = 0; i < *L; i++)
    { 
         picture[i] = (pixel*) malloc(*C * sizeof(pixel));

         for (j = 0; j < *C; j++)
         {  
            fgets(line, sizeof line, arq);
            sscanf(line, "%d", &picture[i][j].r);
            fgets(line, sizeof line, arq);          
            sscanf(line, "%d", &picture[i][j].g);
            fgets(line, sizeof line, arq);          
            sscanf(line, "%d", &picture[i][j].b);
         }
    }

    return picture;
}
//=============================================

void output(pixel** picture, int* L, int* C, char* arquivo, char* etapa)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    char name[30] = "";
    strcat(name, etapa);
    strcat(name, arquivo);

    FILE *file = NULL;
    file = fopen(name, "w");

    //formato da imagem
    fprintf(file, "P3\n");

    //comentario
    fprintf(file, "# Arquivo PPM de saida\n");

    //tamanho da imagem
    fprintf(file, "%d %d\n", *L, *C);

    //componente RGB
    fprintf(file, "255\n");

    for(i = 0; i < *L; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < *C; j++) 
        {
            fprintf(file, "%d\n", picture[i][j].r);
            fprintf(file, "%d\n", picture[i][j].g);
            fprintf(file, "%d\n", picture[i][j].b);         
        }

    }

    fclose(file);
}

//============================================

int main()
{
    FILE *arq = NULL;
    pixel** imagem = NULL;
    int linhas = 0;
    int colunas = 0;

    printf("\nEspecifique o arquivo de imagem a ser analisado: ");
    //armazena o nome do arquivo
    char *arquivo = (char*) malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", arquivo);

    //Abre o arquivo, e, se nao for possivel, envia mensagem de erro
    if ((arq = fopen(arquivo, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nErro.\nImpossivel abrir arquivo especificado.\n");
        exit(1);
    }   

    //imagem original
    imagem = create_picture(arq, &linhas, &colunas);
    output(imagem, &linhas, &colunas, arquivo, "original_");
    //imagem filtrada
    imagem = gauss_filter(imagem, &linhas, &colunas);
    output(imagem, &linhas, &colunas, arquivo, "gauss_");

    free(arquivo);  
    free(arq);  
    free(imagem);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tem como por a imagem sendo filtrada e os resultados obtidos? Se for possível (e você tiver acesso) o resultado desejado também?

Comment: Pronto, imagens adicionadas. Como não tenho acesso à PPM final, coloquei uma versão JPG de como deveria ser o resultado após a aplicação do filtro.

Comment: @Korujao: Tem como postar a versão completa do código que gerou a imagem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código da sua pergunta se trata de um algoritmo de processamento de imagens chamado [`Filtro Espacial`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtragem_no_dom%C3%ADnio_espacial).

`Filtragem Espacial` refere-se ao plano da imagem, envolve a manipulação direta dos pixels da imagem utilizando uma [`Máscara Espacial`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)), também conhecida como [`kernel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).

A `Filtragem Espacial` consiste no deslocamento da máscara *`H`* sobre a imagem original *`I`* onde se calcula a soma dos produtos em cada região *`(v,u)`*, compondo uma nova imagem filtrada *`I'`*:

[image: Filtro Espacial]

Os valores das máscaras são coeficientes e o processo de filtragem é similar a um operação matemática denominada [`Convolução`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Quando se diz que um `Filtro Espacial` é *Gaussiano* significa que a máscara usada no processo de `Convolução` é uma representação discreta de uma [`Função de Gauss`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function):

[image: Curva de Gauss - Representacao Discreta em plano 5x5]

Em essência, a implementação do seu `Filtro Espacial` está correta! O erro do seu código está no momento em que você lê e grava o [cabeçalho do arquivo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PGM_example) `.ppm`, repare que você está está lendo as dimensões da imagem de forma invertida. Você está trocando a quantidade de linhas com a quantidade de colunas da imagem.

Segue um código testado e comentado capaz de aplicar um `Filtro Espacial Gaussiano de Smooth` em uma imagem no formato `.ppm`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_MAX_LEN    (64)

/* Representa um pixel da imagem */
typedef struct pixel_s
{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
} pixel_t;


/* Representa uma imagem */
typedef struct image_s
{
    pixel_t ** buf;
    int ncols;
    int nrows;
} image_t;


image_t * image_create( int ncols, int nrows )
{
    int i = 0;

    image_t * img = (image_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(image_t) );

    img->buf = (pixel_t**) calloc( nrows, sizeof(pixel_t*) );

    for( i = 0; i < nrows; i++ )
        img->buf[i] = (pixel_t*) calloc( ncols, sizeof(pixel_t) );

    img->ncols = ncols;
    img->nrows = nrows;

    return img;
}

void image_destroy( image_t * img )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < img->nrows; i++ )
        free(img->buf[i]);

    free(img->buf);
    free(img);
}

pixel_t * image_read_pixel( image_t * img, int col, int row )
{
    /* Nao permite leitura fora das fronteiras da imagem original */
    if( col >= img->ncols ) col = img->ncols - 1;
    if( row >= img->nrows ) row = img->nrows - 1;
    if( col < 0 ) col = 0;
    if( row < 0 ) row = 0;

    return &img->buf[row][col];
}

image_t * image_gaussian_smooth_filter( image_t * img )
{
    int x, y, col, row, newpx;
    pixel_t * px;
    int sum, div;

    int kernel[5][5] = {{ 2,  4,  5,  4, 2 },
                        { 4,  9, 12,  9, 4 },
                        { 5, 12, 15, 12, 5 },
                        { 4,  9, 12,  9, 4 },
                        { 2,  4,  5,  4, 2 }};

    /* Debug */
    printf( "Filtrando Imagem: tipo=P3; nrows=%d; ncols=%d\n", img->nrows, img->ncols );

    image_t * newimg = image_create( img->ncols, img->nrows );

    for( row = 0; row < img->nrows; row++ )
    {
        for( col = 0; col < img->ncols; col++ )
        {
            sum = 0;
            div = 0;

            for( y = 0; y < 5; y++ )
            {
                for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
                {
                    px = image_read_pixel( img,  col + (x - 2), row + (y - 2) );
                    sum += ( px->red *  kernel[y][x] );
                    div += kernel[y][x];
                }
            }

            newpx = sum / div;

            newimg->buf[row][col].red = newpx;
            newimg->buf[row][col].green = newpx;
            newimg->buf[row][col].blue = newpx;
        }
    }

    return newimg;
}

int image_save( const char * file, image_t * img )
{
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    FILE * pf = fopen( file , "w" );

    if(!pf)
        return -1;

    fprintf( pf, "P3\n");
    fprintf( pf, "# Arquivo PPM de saida\n");
    fprintf( pf, "%d %d\n", img->ncols, img->nrows );
    fprintf( pf, "255\n" );

    /* Debug */
    printf( "Gravando Imagem: arquivo=%s; tipo=P3; nrows=%d; ncols=%d; componente=255\n", file, img->nrows, img->ncols );

    for( row = 0; row < img->nrows; row++)
    {
        for( col = 0; col < img->ncols; col++ )
        {
            fprintf( pf, "%u\n", img->buf[row][col].red );
            fprintf( pf, "%u\n", img->buf[row][col].green );
            fprintf( pf, "%u\n", img->buf[row][col].blue );
        }
    }

    fclose(pf);

    return 0;
}

image_t * image_load( const char * file )
{
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;
    char tipo[3];
    char line[LINE_MAX_LEN];
    int header_index = 0;
    int componente = 0;
    int nrows = 0;
    int ncols = 0;
    image_t * img = NULL;

    FILE * pf = fopen( file, "r" );

    if(!pf)
        return NULL;

    /* Carega o Header do Arquivo PPM */
    while( fgets( line, LINE_MAX_LEN, pf ) )
    {
        if( header_index == 0 )
        {
            sscanf( line, "%s", tipo );
            header_index++;
        }
        else if(header_index == 1 )
        {
            header_index++;
        }
        else if(header_index == 2 )
        {
            sscanf( line, "%d %d", &ncols, &nrows );
            header_index++;
        }
        else if( header_index == 3 )
        {
            sscanf(line, "%d", &componente);
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Debug */
    printf( "Carregando Imagem: arquivo=%s; tipo=%s; nrows=%d; ncols=%d; componente=%d\n", file, tipo, nrows, ncols, componente );

    /* Verifica se o tipo do arquivo eh P3 */
    if( tipo[0] != 'P' || tipo[1] != '3')
    {
        fclose(pf);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Cria uma imagem em branco */
    img = image_create( ncols, nrows );

    /* Carrega imagem */
    for( row = 0; row < nrows; row++)
    {
        for( col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
        {
            /* Componente Vermelho */
            fgets(line, LINE_MAX_LEN, pf );
            sscanf( line, "%hhu", &img->buf[row][col].red );

            /* Componente Verde */
            fgets( line, LINE_MAX_LEN, pf );
            sscanf( line, "%hhu", &img->buf[row][col].green );

            /* Componente Azul */
            fgets( line, LINE_MAX_LEN, pf );
            sscanf( line, "%hhu", &img->buf[row][col].blue );
        }
    }

    fclose(pf);

    return img;
}

int main( void )
{
    /* Carrega imagem a partir do arquivo */
    image_t * original = image_load( "imagem_cinza.ppm" );

    if(!original)
    {
        printf("Erro ao carregar imagem PPM.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Aplica filtro */
    image_t * filtered = image_gaussian_smooth_filter( original );

    /* Grava imagem filtrada em arquivo */
    int ret = image_save("imagem_filtrada.ppm", filtered );

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printf("Erro ao salvar imagem PPM.\n");

        /* Libera memoria ocupada pelas imagens */
        image_destroy(filtered);
        image_destroy(original);

        return 1;
    }

    /* Libera memoria ocupada pelas imagens */
    image_destroy(filtered);
    image_destroy(original);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Carregando Imagem: arquivo=imagem_cinza.ppm; tipo=P3; nrows=480; ncols=610; componente=255
Filtrando Imagem: tipo=P3; nrows=480; ncols=610
Gravando Imagem: arquivo=imagem_filtrada.ppm; tipo=P3; nrows=480; ncols=610; componente=255
```

Imagem Original: [*(Download .ppm)*](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07407635685403365126)
[image: Imagem Original]

Imagem Filtrada: [*(Download .ppm)*](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07768479128529622188)
[image: Imagem Filtrada]

Referências:

1. http://dcm.ffclrp.usp.br/~murta/PIM/PIM_2.pdf
2. http://www.facom.ufu.br/~backes/gsi058/Aula06-FiltragemEspacial.pdf
3. http://www.coe.utah.edu/~cs4640/slides/Lecture5.pdf

Comment: @Korujao: Poste o código completo responsável pela geração das imagens anexadas a sua pergunta que eu edito a resposta com um código 100% funcional. No aguardo.

Comment: Adicionada as funções que usei para gerar e salvar as imagens.

Comment: @Korujao: Segue edição final da resposta.